# Is there an ANSI Specification for the PIVOT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, oracle11g, pivot, ansi-sql

Lately I asked the question [How can I use PIVOT to show simultaneous average and count in its cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782168/how-can-i-use-pivot-to-show-simultationly-average-and-count-in-its-cells)

The question is answered for SQL-Server (2005+) and Oracle (11g +)

Obviously the sql-server implementation is rather limited and Oracle implementation yields strange column names.

Are these independent solutions or are there based on some ANSI-standards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't in [ANSI-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

The later versions are not freely available (as far as I can tell) except a draft [SQL:2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003). Also not mentioned

Note: neither pivot nor cross-tab are mentioned

Comment: OMG ponies says(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054533/to-use-pivot-table-as-view-in-sql-server): Read the PIVOT tag wiki page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pivot/info