# To Use Pivot Table as View in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, pivot

I have a pivot table that I prepared in SQL, but I can't use it in View. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Provide detail -- this doesn't make any sense to me.  Why do you need a pivot table in a view?  How do you want to use the table and/or view?  Also, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: @bedreddin
: are you asking if a cross tab using PIVOT can be contained in a  view? If so, the answer is 'Yes'

Comment: And can you show the SQL for this "pivot table"? BTW, "pivot table" is something that Excel does. I don't believe there is such a thing in SQL.

Comment: @OMG: I know. It does not produce something called a "pivot table".

Comment: A "Pivot Table" is an Excel data structure.  A "View" is a SQL object.  You will have to provide more information before we can answer your question.

Comment: @OMG Ponies Is Pivot ANSI ? cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842726/is-there-an-ansi-specification-for-the-pivot-statement

Comment: @bernd_k: Read the [PIVOT tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pivot/info).

Answer (score 0):

See this answer to a somewhat related question:

[sql-pivoted-table-is-read-only-and-cells-cant-be-edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012058/573261)

You need to make the view updateable via an INSTEAD OF trigger, and there are specific conditions to using that trigger, such as the pivot-table view being fully identifiable to source record-column.