# SQL query to find dups in columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is a subset of the data that I need to query. "hat I need to do is 
take any routing that matches yet has a diff dept and concatenate the values
in a separate column. See below for before and after. Any suggestions on how 
to do this would be great?

This is my query:

```
select mcrp27, irkitl
from f0006
join f3003
on mcmcu = irmcu 
where mcrp27 <> ' '
and irmmcu = ' 20101556'
order by mcrp27
```

Before:

```
ROUTING DEPT
======= =======  
R335700 1
R335800 1
R335900 1
R336000 1
R336100 1
R336200 1
R336300 1
R336500 1
R435500 1
R435501 1
R435600 1
R435700 1
R436400 1
R336100 2
R336200 2
R336300 2
R436400 2
R436400 3
R335300 5
R335300 6
R331400 7
R331500 7
R331600 7
R331900 7
R332100 7
R332200 7
R332400 7
R332500 7
R332600 7
R332700 7
```

After:

```
R335700 1   
R335800 1   
R335900 1   
R336000 1   
R336100 1   2   
R336200 1   2   
R336300 1   2   
R336500 1   
R435500 1   
R435501 1   
R435600 1   
R435700 1   
R436400 1   2   3
R335300 5   6   
R331400 7   
R331500 7   
R331600 7   
R331900 7   
R332100 7   
R332200 7   
R332400 7   
R332500 7   
R332600 7   
R332700 7
```

Comment: What database is that? I mean you could use [PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842726/is-there-an-ansi-specification-for-the-pivot-statement) but that's not ANSI SQL.

Comment: Do you want to aggregate per ROUTING and get a string of their DEPTs, e.g. 'R436400' | '1,2,3'?

Comment: It is JD Edwards (PL/SQL) oracle...How would the aggregate query look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there can be any number of DEPTs per ROUTING and a SQL query can only return a before-known number of columns, I'd suggest returning the DEPTs in a comma-separated string. So you'd have two columns: ROUTING and DEPTS.

```
select routing, listagg(dept, ',') within group (order by dept) as depts
from mytable
group by routing
order by routing;
```